# Ghosting PHP functions like in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

### Original Question

Since a recent version of php added anonymous functions, is there a way to extend functions? in Javascript I'd do:

```
var temp = immaFunction;
immaFunction = function(){
  //do some random stuff
  temp.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

### Result

As of 5.3, PHP has first class anonymous functions.
A few points to consider however(will be filling this with more as I mess around with it.):

- You must import any external variables you want to use. (Example 1)

### Examples

Example 1:

```
$foo = "bar";
$fooBar = function() use ($foo){
  echo $foo;
}
$fooBar(); //bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.3 supports that
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: One problem if you copy an existing function, it var_dump's to a string of the functions name.

Comment: It does not support the same syntax exactly.  To use local variables, you need to add the `use` clause:  `$func = function() use ($temp) { $temp->something(); }`.  Unlike JS, the functions do not inherit the local scope by default (You need to "bind" them in using the `use` clause to retain access)...

Answer (score 0):

I believe PHP also has functions as first-class objects. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Functions

Iznogood is right.